# Webpack's removes classnames when minifying/uglifying ES6 code with inheritance

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, uglifyjs, uglifyjs2

Webpack's removes *classnames* when minifying/uglifying ES6 code with inheritance:

There's [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) code which we try to minify/uglify:

**Class Child**:

```
const ParentClass = require('parent');

class Child extends ParentClass{
    constructor(){
        super();
    }
}

module.exports = Child;
```

**index.js** which invokes `Child` class:

```
const Child = require('./classes_so/child');

let child = new Child();

console.log(child.constructor.name);
```

**Module Parent** inside `node_modules`:

```
class Parent {
    constructor() {
        if (this.constructor.name === 'Parent'){
            throw new TypeError("Parent class is abstract - cant be instance");
        }
    }

}

module.exports = Parent;
```

The whole output I'll post to the end of the question, here I want to post only relevant lines which I think cause a wrong behavior (lines 33-37 from original output):

```
n.exports = class extends r {
        constructor() {
            super();
        }
    };
```

---

Why a *classname* is missing here: `class extends r`? I expect that value will be mangled but will exist, can I consider it as a bug? I tried to use `keep_classnames` flag but it keeps original class names which unacceptable.

**We're using**:

- Webpack: 3.11.0 (tried with 4, same behavior)
- uglifyjs-webpack-plugin: 1.2.4 (tried with different plugins)
- NodeJS: v6.9.1 and v8.9.1 (same output)
- Complete project which demonstrate the issue: [webpack-uglify-inheritence](https://github.com/anatoly314/webpack-uglify-inheritence)

**Update 1**:

- Open an issue at [uglifyjs-webpack-plugin repository](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/uglifyjs-webpack-plugin/issues/269)

Our `webpack.config.js`:

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
const UglifyJsPlugin = require('uglifyjs-webpack-plugin');
const path = require('path');
const fs = require('fs');

const nodeModules = {};
const localDependencies = ['.bin'];
fs.readdirSync('node_modules')
    .filter(function (x) {
        return localDependencies.indexOf(x) === -1;
    })
    .forEach(function (mod) {
        nodeModules[mod] = 'commonjs ' + mod;
    });

try {


    module.exports = {
        target: 'node',
        node: {
            console: false,
            global: false,
            process: false,
            Buffer: false,
            __filename: true,
            __dirname: true
        },

        entry: './index_so.js',

        output: {
            path: path.join(__dirname, 'build'),
            filename: 'index.js'
        },

        externals: nodeModules,
        plugins: [
            new webpack.IgnorePlugin(/\.(css|less)$/),
            new webpack.BannerPlugin({
                banner: 'require("source-map-support").install();',
                raw: true,
                entryOnly: false
            })
        ],
        devtool: 'sourcemap',

        module: {
            loaders: [
                {test: /\.json$/, loader: "json-loader"}
            ]
        },

        plugins: [
            new UglifyJsPlugin({
                uglifyOptions: {
                    compress: {
                        warnings: false
                    },
                    keep_classnames: false,
                    mangle: true,
                    output: {
                        beautify: true
                    }
                }
            })
        ]
    };
}
catch (e) {
    console.error(e);
}
```

The whole minified/uglified code from the example above:

```
!function(n) {
    var t = {};
    function e(r) {
        if (t[r]) return t[r].exports;
        var o = t[r] = {
            i: r,
            l: !1,
            exports: {}
        };
        return n[r].call(o.exports, o, o.exports, e), o.l = !0, o.exports;
    }
    e.m = n, e.c = t, e.d = function(n, t, r) {
        e.o(n, t) || Object.defineProperty(n, t, {
            configurable: !1,
            enumerable: !0,
            get: r
        });
    }, e.n = function(n) {
        var t = n && n.__esModule ? function() {
            return n.default;
        } : function() {
            return n;
        };
        return e.d(t, "a", t), t;
    }, e.o = function(n, t) {
        return Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(n, t);
    }, e.p = "", e(e.s = 0);
}([ function(n, t, e) {
    let r = new (e(1))();
    console.log(r.constructor.name);
}, function(n, t, e) {
    const r = e(2);
    n.exports = class extends r {
        constructor() {
            super();
        }
    };
}, function(n, t) {
    n.exports = require("parent");
} ]);
```

Comment: `n.exports = class extends r {` is a correct syntax. Do you get any error when you run your code, because of the missing `class`  name?

Comment: I mean why are you ok that the class name is mangled, but it is not ok if it is missing? If you don't care about the name why do you care about its existence?

Comment: Yes, I get an error. We rely on a code `this.constructor.name`. If a code isn't minified it works otherwise it returns or an empty string (when the code runs in NodeJS v6.9.1) or a name of the class from which it was inherited in our case, it's `Parent` class what is definitely wrong. The last one happens when we run minified code on NodeJS v8.9.1

Comment: I've created a simple project which demonstrate an issue, you can download it here: https://github.com/anatoly314/webpack-uglify-inheritence

Comment: But why do you want to realy on `this.constructor.name === 'Parent'` in a context where names can be mangled? I don't see that there is any bug with the minification, the bug is in my opinion in your code, and you should write somethign like `if (this.constructor == Parent){`

Comment: Our `node_modules` don't mangled, so if somebody will use it, it will contain the whole name. In an example a `Parent` inside `node_modules` so it isn't mangled.

Comment: btw, maintainer of `uglifyjs-webpack-plugin` suggest that it's likely a bug, why do think that it's correct syntax?

Comment: The syntax is valid, because the standard defined it as valid. Even if the error occurs due to the minification, the reason for the error is not this. The reason is that you use code that seems to work at first glance, but should not be used like this in general and especially not if the code or the code that uses it can be minified.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem in the given setup is not in the code of webpack or uglify but in this part of the code:

```
class Parent {
  constructor() {
    if (this.constructor.name === 'Parent') {
      throw new TypeError("Parent class is abstract - cant be instance");
    }
  }

}

module.exports = Parent;
```

The `this.constructor.name === 'Parent'` relays on the the `class`/`function`  name, to test if `Parent` was directly instanced.

Instead of relaying one the name which can result in various problems, it would be a better idea to test if the constructor equals the class.

```
class Parent {
  constructor() {
    if (this.constructor === Parent) {
      throw new TypeError("Parent class is abstract - cant be instance");
    }
  }

}

module.exports = Parent;
```

Comment: It doesn't work in mangled version.  `this.constructor` returns `Parent` in both case, when object was instantiated from `Parent` or `Client`.

Comment: The response depends on a version of NodeJS, in v6.9.1 it returns an empty *classname* on the extended constructor and `Parent` if object instantiated from `abstract` object. In v8.9.1 it returns `Parent` when object instantiated from inherited or abstract class both.

Comment: @Anatoly I tested it with `6.9.1` and newer and `8.9.1`, and `this.constructor === Parent` returns `false` if `new Child` and `true` if `new ParentClass`. Are you sure that you correclty updated and relaoded your `webpack-parent-class`.

Answer (score 0):

Try my lib [typescript-class-helpers](https://github.com/darekf77/typescript-class-helpers)

```
import { CLASS } from 'typescript-class-helpers/browser';

@CLASS.NAME('Parent')
class Parent {
    constructor() {
        if (CLASS.getNameFromObject(child) === 'Parent'){
            throw new TypeError("Parent class is abstract - cant be instance");
        }
    }

}

@CLASS.NAME('Child')
class Child extends ParentClass{
    constructor(){
        super();
    }
}

let child = new Child();

console.log(CLASS.getNameFromObject(child)); // Child
```

With this you can minify your classes names and everything will be ok.